# Combining abc.abstractmethod with other decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

Say I have a class like the following:

```
from functools import wrap
import abc

class Test:
    def hello (self):
        print("hello world!")

    def decorator (f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapped (inst, *args, **kwargs):
            inst.hello()
            return f(inst, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped

    @abc.abstractmethod
    # @decorator ???
    def fn (self):
        return
```

Is there any way of ensuring that all implementations of the abstract method, fn(), will be decorated with decorator()? Either by enforcing that the implementation explicitly includes the decoration, or by decorating all implementations automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not. ABCs can only dictate that certain attributes are present, either as methods or properties. They are not equipped to dictate that a decorator is used.

ABCs specify the *interface*, not the implementation; a decorator is an implementation detail.

Comment: Thank you. Suppose I have a decorator that any implementations have to use in order to work properly. Is there a neat way of enforcing its use? Is that an indication of poor design? Is leaving a comment in the docstring saying "use this decorator in your implementation!" the only way around it?

Comment: @Pig: there isn't. Python isn't really a language for enforcing implementation details like that. Document, and trust that people will read. You could provide tools to test the code (like a linter) or test for specific decorator-supplied flags at runtime if you don't trust the users of your API.

Comment: It's for a personal project, but I thought it would cut down on code duplication if I could achieve that effect. Thanks for clarifying!